Gate Key-pers: 2nd player strategy
Gate Key-pers is a guessing game which appears in the new Super Mario Party. Here's how it goes:
There are $m$ keys and $n\leq m$ doors. Each door is unlocked by a unique key. Players take turns choosing a key and a door, and if there is a match, they unlock the door and pass through. The last player to open a door loses.
Suppose I'm playing second and the first player failed to choose a matching pair. Which option gives the best odds at unlocking a door?
a) Choosing the same key but a different door.
b) Choosing the same door but a different key.
c) Choosing a different pair altogether.
Thanks!

You can imagine that you have other $m-n$ non-existing doors, in such a way every key opens a door, even if some keys don't open any of the subset of doors that actually let players pass through.
So, after a match fails, we can easily calculate the chance of each strategy.

Choosing the same door with a different key offers a probability of $\frac{1}{m-1}$: that door has to be opened by some key.
Choosing the same key, but another door still offers a probability of $\frac{1}{m-1}$: if we take into account also the non existing door, that key has to open a door and there are $m-1$ doors remaining.
Choosing another key and another door: say that the first player choose key $a$ to open door $A$ and failed. We choose key $b$ to open door $B$. We know that there is a probability of $\frac{1}{m-1}$ that $b$ opens $A$, so there is a probability of $1 - \frac{1}{m-1}$ that $b$ opens any other (existing or not) door. Since there are $m-1$ of them, by simmetry, the probability $P(B, b)$ that $b$ opens $B$ is:
$$P(B,b) = \frac{m-2}{(m-1)^2}$$

